# washer method to find volume of rotation about some line

Tags: integration

Suppose we have two functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ and we want to find the volume of rotation about some line $x = $AOR (axis of rotation) or $y =$ AOR

In my textbook, i haven't found any relevant information about that.
So, while watching some tutorials, i found the following formula ->

$$\int_a^b Pi(AOR - outer) - Pi(AOR - iner) \,dx/dy$$

So, now i have a question, does this formula always work?

Because when i was watching other tutorials i saw the following ->

Find the volume of rotation bounded by y = x, y = sqrt(x) and rotate about x = -3

and the integral looked something like this ->

$$\int_0^1 Pi(3+y)^2 - Pi(3+y)^2 \,dy$$

And this definitely does not look like this formula

$$\int_a^b Pi(AOR - outer) - Pi(AOR - iner) \,dx/dy$$

Can someone clarify this for me and write a general formula or algorithm on how to deal with such problems, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your formula is incorrect. Here is the correct formula, where $f(x)$ is the outer function and $g(x)$ is the inner one:

$$π\int_a^b\ (f(x))^2-(g(x))^2\,dx$$

As for why this works, understand what an integral is actually *doing* to solve the problem. An integral is actually an infinite sum of infinite tiny things. Consider, for instance, rotating a line from the point (0,1) to (1,1) about the x axis. The shape you'd get is a circle, whose area was $πr^2 $, and in this case $r = 1$, so the area would be π. Now imagine that circle were actually an infinite thin cylinder, such that its volume were $πr^2dx$, where dx is an infinitely small change in x. This is what you plug into the integral; the integral is just adding up an infinite number of these infinitely thin discs to give you a finite volume: the volume of revolution, only in that case, the radius of each circle is f(x).

As for the "outer-inner" business, when you rotate an area with an inner area, you're really taking one volume of revolution and hollowing out the volume of another volume of revolution inside. The formula is really just saying

$$\int_a^b\ πr^2dx-\int_a^b\ πr^2dx$$ 
Just remember that it comes from the volume of an infinitely thin cylinder.

This formula always works as long as one curve is always outside the other, if not, try using the shell method.

See these videos for a full explanation:

https://www.khanacademy.org/math/integral-calculus/solid_revolution_topic/disc-method/v/disk-method-around-x-axis

https://www.khanacademy.org/math/integral-calculus/solid_revolution_topic/disc-method/v/disc-method-washer-method-for-rotation-around-x-axis

https://www.khanacademy.org/math/integral-calculus/solid_revolution_topic/disc-method/v/generalizing-the-washer-method

Comment: but what happens when you rotate about some line?

Comment: Just account for the change in radius. $$π\int_a^b\ (f(x)-A)^2-(g(x)-A)^2\,dx$$ Like if you're rotating the area between $y=x^2$ and $y=x$ about $y = -1$, you do $$π\int_0^1\ ((x+1)^2-(x^2+1)^2)dx $$

Comment: but isn't it going to be other way around ? Axis of rotation - f(x)...? Or if it is inside the square brackets, it does not matter?

Comment: It's f(x) - AOR. Suppose you want to rotate $y=x^2$ about y=1 from 0 to 1. Because the radius of each cylinder is now 1 unit less than it would have been if we were rotating about y=0, we do $$π\int_0^1\ (f(x)-1)^2dx$$ But it doesn't really matter anyway because we're squaring it, meaning $$(f(x)-a)^2 = (a-f(x))^2$$